# Unable to output video to 6 monitors with 2 AMD graphics cards and proprietary drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I have 6 various monitors, and 2 identical MSI R9 270 graphics cards. I have 3 monitors connected to each card via DisplayPort, HDMI, and one DVI. I decided to use the older Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (64 bit) after reading this: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04.

When using Windows 10 (64 bit), I was able to configure a layout with the 6 monitors very easily right after intallation. On Ubuntu 14.04, after installing the proprietary fglrx-updates driver, I am only able to get video output using the first graphics card. Catalyst Control Center only detects the first graphics card, and the 3 monitors connected to it. The other 3 monitors remain in standby mode (powered on, but not receiving any video input).

I have tried adding the 2nd graphics card to /etc/X11/xorg.conf by using the PCI bus address, and it did nothing. Though, according to my understanding, xorg.conf is for the open source driver. I would probably be better off using the proprietary driver, since I plan to play games on my PC, and would like better performance.

Here is my system configuration:

- CPU: AMD FX-8350 8 core CPU overclocked to 4.4GHz
- GPUs: 2 identical MSI R9-270
- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 rev4.0
- SSD: Samsung 850 EVO 250GB
- HDD: 2TB 7200rpm HGST
- PSU: Corsair HX850
- RAM: 2x8GB DDR3 Corsair Vengeance Pro 1600MHz
- Monitors: 2x AOC i2367fh (both HDMI), one old acer monitor (DVI to VGA on GPU1, and 3 old dell monitors (one is DVI on GPU2 and the others are DisplayPort to VGA)

Here is my output from: lspci | grep VGA

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM]
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM]
```

Here is my output  from: sudo lshw -c video

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:40 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:fea00000-fea3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea40000-fea5ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:41 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:fe600000-fe63ffff ioport:b000(size=256) memory:fe640000-fe65ffff
```

This is my current xorg.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card2"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```